# Joomla component development - how to organize?

Tags: component, development, mvc

I am trying to write simple component for Joomla 3 to show catalogue and products.

I did made my model catalogue and it works ok - it shows list of all products with pagination, but I also want to make clickable link for each product to open detailed product info (this page should be accessible by alias).

What is a correct way to organize this scheme in MVC?

Should I make a new model (??) but how to make aliases and give item's id to this page?

I did read a lot of tutorials but I never seen any tutorial with library or catalogue example.

Thanks in advance, guys

Answer (score 1):

I´ll describe the way I did it.

I created a system plugin that responds to the `onAfterInitialise` event to create a new router.

```
$router = $app->getRouter();
```

So I can use my own rules:

```
$router->attachBuildRule(array($myRouterRules, 'build'));
$router->attachParseRule(array($myRouterRules, 'parse'));
```

The alias of my product is:

```
alias-p2
```

For instance for a product named: This is a great product with ID = 5 the alias would be:

```
this-is-a-great-product-p5
```

The my parse rule will identify if the URL ends in -pX and if so it will send the url query for my detail product screen.